# Контекстный менеджер, не возвращающий значения

Tags: python, генераторы, yield

Я хочу написать контекстный менеджер, который выглядит примерно так:

```
@contexlib.contextmanager
def process_started(process: mylib.Process) -> XXX: # ?
    process.start()

    try:
        yield XXX # ?
    except BaseException as e: 
        raise e # reraise any exception
    finally:
        process.finish()
```

То есть ему не надо возвращать какое-то значение, должен использоваться так:

```
with process_started(process):
    do_background_stuff()
```

Что в таком случае надо указывать вместо `XXX`? Какой возвращаемый тип и значение у `yield`?

Comment: У `yield` ничего, в аннотации можно `None`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов что означает выражение `yield `? Вернуть `None`? И в чём отличие от `yield None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не возвращайте. В аннотации укажите `None`. `yield` поддерживает такой синтаксис (который не отличается от `yield None`):

```
import contextlib


@contextlib.contextmanager
def f():
    print('before')
    yield
    print('after')


with f():
    print('within')
```

> ```
> $ python yield.py 
> before
> within
> after
> ```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает это выражение? Какой у него тип и в чём отличие от `yield None`?

Comment: `yield` <---> `yield None`, тип `None`

Answer (score 1):

`yield`  действительно эквивалентно `yield None`, однако правильной аннотацией будет `typing.Generator[None, None, None]` (вместо `None` допустим его тип, но принято `None` писать), иначе тот же PyCharm будет подчёркивать ваши вызовы `next()` и `send()`. Возможный вариант без подчёркиваний `typing.NoReturn`, но, судя по комментам https://stackoverflow.com/a/36797437, его не принято использовать в такой ситуации.

Comment: Вместо `typing.Generator[None, None, None]` с Python 3.9 лучше использовать `collections.abc.Generator[None, None, None]`